# Getting error message while trying to create custom indicator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i'm trying to create this custom indicator.
but getting error - **" Error at 31:11 Mismatched input 'end of line without line continuation' expecting ')' "**

Can someone Help please

```
//@version=5
indicator("Fear Prediction Market Timing", overlay = true)

// Input for the VIX values at different time horizons
vix9d = input.int(30, title="VIX 9-Day")
vix3m = input.int(20, title="VIX 3-Month")
vix6m = input.int(15, title="VIX 6-Month")

// Color definitions
var color greenColor = color.green
var color yellowColor = color.yellow
var color redColor = color.red

// Determine the color based on your strategy conditions
plot_color = vix9d < vix3m and vix3m < vix6m ? greenColor : na
plot_color := vix9d > vix3m ? yellowColor : plot_color
plot_color := vix9d > vix3m and vix3m < vix6m ? redColor : plot_color

// Plot the colored background
plot(plot_color, style=plot.style_histogram, color=color.new(plot_color, 90))

// Plot the colored label based on the color condition
var labelColor = na
labelColor := vix9d < vix3m and vix3m < vix6m ? greenColor : labelColor
labelColor := vix9d > vix3m ? yellowColor : labelColor
labelColor := vix9d > vix3m and vix3m < vix6m ? redColor : labelColor

label.new(
    x=bar_index,
    y=high,
    text="FPMT",
    color=labelColor,
    style=label.style_labelup,
    textcolor=color.white,
    size=size.small
)


// Plot the VIX values on the chart for reference
plot(vix9d, title="VIX 9-Day", color=color.blue)
plot(vix3m, title="VIX 3-Month", color=color.orange)
plot(vix6m, title="VIX 6-Month", color=color.purple)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message gives you a hint. Its at line 31.

```
label.new(x=bar_index
 , y=high
 , text="FPMT"
 , color=labelColor
 , style=label.style_labelup
 , textcolor=color.white
 , size=size.small
 )
```

You did use four white-spaces which creates a local-scope that you didn't wanted.
To put one line of code into several lines you need **less than four white-spaces**.
And this will automatically create a vertical line before the code.
A local-scope is used for `loops` and `if` statements, as example.

**I spotted some more errors...**

When creating a variable with `NaN` value then you need to **declare its type** too.

```
labelColor = color(na)
```

Same rules apply when using `?:` to create a variable which can result into `NaN`...

```
color plot_color = vix9d < vix3m and vix3m < vix6m ? greenColor : na
```

Last but not least, you did a weird think I could not decipher...

```
plot(plot_color, style=plot.style_histogram, color=color.new(plot_color, 90))
```

In the case you want to create a histogram, **series value of a plot has to be a number**.
To color the background of the chart you should use `bgcolor()`.